# Changing to custom domain on Github Pages causes create-react-app with react-router to stop working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages, create-react-app

So my app, /portfolio, works fine when deployed to the normal github hosting.  You can see that [here](https://jacobgranberry.github.io/portfolio/).  But when I switch to a custom domain the app doesn't want to mount.  I did a bit of research and assumed it has to do with react-router but I can't seem to figure it out.

Heres my BrowserRouter code:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>,
```

Which leaders to /portolio/ as the basename.  I *assume* it should correctly change when on the custom domain but I played with it to no effect.

Any hints on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out create-react-app docs actually highlight this problem.  Github pages doesn't play well with BrowserRouter.  Theres a sort of hack in the documents [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) that worked swimmingly for me.